# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Bootsrap Notify

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've just include the notify Plugin for bootstrap into my page. When I call

```
 echo '<script>$( document ).ready(function() {$.notify("Hello World");});</script>';
```

the console told me this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Here are my Javascript includes.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/contact.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/counter.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/page.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/responsive-menu.js"></script>
```

Comment: where your code is placed?

Comment: either you are trying to use `$` before jQuery.js is loaded or jQuery.js is not loading or perhaps `jQuery.noConflict()` is being used such as in a wordpress theme

Comment: In the php section on top of the file

Answer (score -1):

Keep your jquery and boostrap js links in the top portion of your head tag and test it again .The problem must be resolved.
This is generally occurs because your doc ready function is loading prior than jquery.js.

```html
<html>
<header>
jquery.js and bootstrap.js at top here
</header>
<body>
</body>
all the remaining links
<script>
document ready here
</script>
<html>
```